# HTML5 video as base64 encode data URI not working in iPad and iPhone browser

Tags: iphone, ipad, base64, html5-video, encode

**I need to play the video as base64 data URI format using HTML5 video tag on iPad and iPhone**, which eventually helps me to make the video offline by storing it in websql,

I got a link which helped me to study the feasibility - http://iandevlin.com/html5/data-uri/video.php (if you take the view source of the link, you will see its well encoded in base64 format)

**I tried this on most of the modern browser's like chrome & firefox in windows machine and safari in mac os, there it worked well.**

So my hoped increased and I tried it in iPhone and iPad, **Well its NOT working there**! I am just getting a **blank BLACK screen** in place of the video control.

**Also I am not getting any error in the safari debug mode as well.** I would like to know whether we can play base 64 encoded video or it just a known issue for ipad and iphone...

Comment: I have just tired it on my Windows Phone, it works like a charm. I can try it later on my dev iphone and report back.

Answer (score 0):

to play video under HTML5 tag you need to provide its content source like images and video/audio files name without any path then only it works well i t

Answer (score 0):

When Base64 media encoding is used you need to take in mind that memory consumption increases substantially, it's not the same as external media inclusion once media is not inside document and may be load in frames consuming only memory you really need.

Using Base64 need to load all the data to perform a decryption, and most mobile browsers take a lot of time to show video because their useful memory is very small (usually most of memory is consumed by operational system) and conversion take a long, when a processes take a long in mobile system, garbage collection know that as a zombie thread and kill it.

Actually is not a good idea assume you can use base64 for video in mobile browser, it should not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found iOS Safari to be pickier than desktop browsers regarding having the correct Mime type in the data uri.  You should make sure you are using the correct one.